# Run Test setup before all tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm using ScalaTest for BDD testing of an app.

The `BeforeAndAfterAll` trait lets me run setup before a running the tests in a specific feature.

But I need to run setup before any of the tests run.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixin the BeforeAndAfterAll trait and implement beforeAll

```
… extends with BeforeAndAfterAll {

   override def beforeAll(configMap: Map[String, Any]) { // Set up code }

 }
```

[ScalaDoc for BeforeAndAfterAll](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll)

Comment: In current ScalaTest (2.2.1) it's `BeforeAndAfterAllConfigMap` and `: ConfigMap`